# Use another query with the same result

Tags: mysql, optimization

I have query:

```
SELECT Name, Surname, Telephone, PersonID FROM Client WHERE Telephone = 
(SELECT MAX(Telephone) FROM Client) OR PersonID = (SELECT MAX(PersonID) 
FROM Client);
```

With result:

```
| Name   | Surname  | Telephone | PersonID    |

| Tyler  | Henry    | 998778781 | 38568215856 |

| Brooke | Thornton | 617196573 | 99412132661 |
```

What other query will give me the same result? I have to compare two queries  in terms of optimization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a *UNION optimization*:

```
SELECT Name, Surname, Telephone, PersonID
FROM Client
WHERE Telephone = (SELECT MAX(Telephone) FROM Client)
UNION
SELECT Name, Surname, Telephone, PersonID
FROM Client
WHERE PersonID = (SELECT MAX(PersonID) FROM Client)
```

If a subset of selected columns is UNIQUE, the query will return the same result.

Given indexes on `(Telephone)` and `(PersonID)` the query should also be much faster on a big table. The reason is that MySQL is not able to use more than one index per table and (sub)query. Splitting the query in two subqueries will allow the engine to use both indexes.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the max `Telephone` and max `PersonID` in a single query and then join it to the table:

```
SELECT c.Name, c.Surname, c.Telephone, c.PersonID 
FROM Client c INNER JOIN ( 
  SELECT MAX(Telephone) Telephone, MAX(PersonID) PesronID FROM Client
)m ON m.Telephone = c.Telephone OR m.PersonID = c.PersonID
```

or with `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT Name, Surname, Telephone, PersonID FROM Client c
WHERE 
  NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM Client 
    WHERE Telephone > c.Telephone 
  )
  OR
  NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM Client 
    WHERE PersonID > c.PersonID 
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what indexes you have.  Without `INDEX(Telephone)` and `INDEX(PersonID)` most of the answers will do table scan(s).

Here's another contender:

```
( SELECT Name, Surname, Telephone, PersonID
    FROM Client
    ORDER BY Telephone DESC LIMIT 1 )
UNION DISTINCT
( SELECT Name, Surname, Telephone, PersonID
    FROM Client
    ORDER BY PersonID DESC LIMIT 1 )
```

This *may* be faster because it does not have subqueries.  However, it *may* give different results if two have the same Telephone or PersonID.

I suggest you run all the formulations against your data to see which is best.

If you want to discuss things further, please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE client` and `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` -- both will give clues of what will/won't run faster.